# How to use a indexed table for faster performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have heard that indexing makes search faster but have newer experienced this practically. I have a table that is indexed on a column. Now how should I run the query so that I make full use of this indexing and get the query faster?

My query currently to the indexed table:

```
String getFS = "select * from TABLEname where number="+MobNum;
```

There is no special performance increase or anything. Am I using the indexes wrong??

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `VPN_UserInformation` (

   `id` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '000000000000000000000',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `number` (`number`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? How many queries do you execute against your table using this index? If you're testing below 10k rows, then you won't see any improvement at all.

Comment: oh i have only 10 rows now for testing purpose but this table in live will have more than 10 lakh rows.

Comment: Change your tests to have at least 10k rows and do the comparison of having the index and not having it. Only there you will see the differences.

Comment: but now also its taking like half a second to get the row. cant i increase this performance????? just ambitious!! :)

Comment: Also will depend on the cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

yes, indexes increase the query performance definitely but there are some hidden things

1. indexes on integer columns are very much faster than indexes on varchar column (your case)
   if possible you can try making number column which is a number(mobile no I am assuming) as integer or bigint and test the performance with and without index on big size
2. instead of using *, write only required columns which will be used in your further processing, if you have more than just id and phone no in that table (which is a best practice and will improve performance)
3. Run reorg and runstats to assure that testplan is using index and no fragmentation is present.